# Spring mongo : How to customize _id without VO?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, primary-key

I am working with MongoDB and Spring 3.2.8.

What I have to do is query to Oracle database with MyBatis and put the ResultMap which returns from the query into Mongo DB.

Situations.

- ResultMap works quite well as I expected. It returns proper `HashMap<String, Object>` or `List<HashMap<String, Object>`
- In that ResultMap, I have an element named 'service_id' which should replace '_id' in mongo.
- Push into mongoDB with MongoTemplate(org.springframework.data.mongo.core) works also well.
- The problem is since mongoDB uses its own '_id' as a primary key, if I put same object it sizes double.

Question.

- How can I use 'service_id' as a primary key of mongo?

Condition.

- Do not use VO.(It means I can not use @id as mongo as described here : http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.0.0.M5/reference/html/#d0e1508)

Part of Source code.
    tmp.insert(map, collectionName);
this tmp is MongoTemplate and I assume that it does not have any method to control '_id'.

Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution but I think it is Orthodox way.

- Put an element into the ReturnMap. e.g. `map.put("_id", map.get("service_id"));`

Now, I can prevent duplication of values.

If there is better way, I will choose that one as an answer :D Thanks